# Buefy: lock the table header and make only the rows scrollable

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, buefy

is there a way I can lock/make the header of the table component stick and only allow the rows to scroll?

Answer (score 0):

One way I normally solve this problem is by using a Sticky Method, like this

There is a **MAJOR con** to this though, Sticky isn't supported by IE6-IE10
Check out the support here, to see if you would be interested in using this
I am currently looking into different ways.
[enter link description here](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=sticky)

```css
table
{
  Position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

thead, th
{
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>Employeed</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
    <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
    <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
    <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
    <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sara</td>
    <td>FL</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: lol @ "MAJOR con". Worldwide browser usage for IE 10 at time of writing this answer was "0.07%" https://gs.statcounter.com/browser-version-market-share/all/worldwide/2019